# Any tips and tricks to avoid or reduce cost of one-to-many joins and non-equi joins when dataset is large?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark

I am wondering how people grapple with large one-to-many joins, and in particular non-equi joins, when they have large data. If the keys of the two tables `A` and `B` are sufficiently repetitive, the output of the join between the two can be nearly the size of |`A`| * |`B`|. This must come up frequently in analytics at large companies, so I am wondering what ways there are to reduce the computation time of these joins.

However, many times `A` and `B` are different tables, and in those cases I do not think `LAG()` can be used.

### Example of a non-equi, one-to-many join

As a simplified example of a situation where a non-equi and one-to-many join might be warranted, I have tables `A` and `B`, with each having a numeric `id` column, a date field `date_created` and some field `group`. For each row in table `A`, I want the `id` column of `A` and all data of the corresponding row in table `B` where `B.date_created` is the largest possible value such that `A.date_created` > `B.date_created` and `A.group = B.group`. In other words, I want the most recent row of table `B` with respect to the `date_created` and `group` fields of each row in column `A`.

#### Code when using a window function

In most use cases where these non-equi-joins come up, `A` and `B` are the same table and the `date_created` fields in fact correspond to the same column. In this situation, I could use the `LAG()` window function:

```
WITH id_tuples AS
(
SELECT A.id,
    LAG(A.id, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY A.group ORDER BY A.date_created) AS lagged_id
FROM A
)
SELECT id_t.id,
    A.*
FROM id_tuples id_t
INNER JOIN A ON A.id = id_t.lagged_id
```

which I believe is more efficient than a self-join. However, this approach is not possible when the columns being compared are different, or belong to different tables.

#### Code when window function is not feasible

I use the following code to compute the most recent row of table `B` for each row in table `A`.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT A.id,
        B.*,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY A.id ORDER BY B.date_created) AS date_rank
    FROM A
    INNER JOIN B ON B.group = A.group
        AND B.date_created < A.date_created
)
WHERE date_rank = 1
```

The problem here is that the grouping variables `A.group` and `B.group` can have only a few distinct values. Then the join becomes nearly a Cartesian join and the number of outputted results in the subquery can be many orders of magnitude greater than the sum of the rows of A and B. This is wasteful since the outer query proceeds to throw out the majority of the results by filtering for `date_rank = 1`.

Is there a better way of structuring the query to reduce the cost of these joins, or avoid them entirely in these situations? I am asking in the abstract but I've found that neither my relational database, nor my Spark cluster (once I move the data there) has enough memory to handle such a join. Even on smaller datasets, this operation takes a large amount of time to run. And I don't believe my dataset is particularly large relative to what others are doing.

Comment: Tagging with [tag:postgresql] (and [tag:database]) and [tag:apache-spark] at the same time doesn't make any sense. These are completely different tools, with different features, execution model and performance considerations.

Comment: First step in( any) optimisation: get rid of the CTE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query can simply be written as:

```
SELECT A.id,
       LAG(A.id, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY A.group ORDER BY A.date_created) AS lagged_id
FROM A;
```

There is no need for the `JOIN`.

For the second query, one method is a lateral join:

```
SELECT A.id, B.*,
FROM A LEFT JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT B.*
      FROM B
      WHERE B.group = A.group AND
            B.date_created < A.date_created
      ORDER BY B.date_created DESC
      FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
     ) B;
```

This should use an index on `B(GROUP, date_created)`.

Comment: I think the first query requires a join if I want the corresponding columns of lagged A

Comment: The second comment looks great; I'll award it the answer in a day or so but I would like to see if others can answer the other, more general parts of the question

Comment: @EricHe . . . No.  Just use `lag()` for the columns that you want.